# What keyboard shortcut is the arrow down?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

What's the shortcut for the little downward arrow in the picture? Since the above shortcut in the printscreen seem to be the "normal" arrow press down, I'm struggling to find what the other arrow is.

Print screen is taken from JetBrains Rider.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s the "Page Down" key. (Or Fn + Down, if you haven’t got one.)